# Why must window changes be in AppDelegate?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to change the window -- not the view -- background, in Xcode 5.

This works fine in AppDelegate, but I'd like to know why it has to be there:

```
// Insert code here to initialize your application
// Background color
[_window setOpaque:NO]; // YES by default
NSColor *semiTransparentBlue =
[NSColor colorWithDeviceRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:1.0 alpha:0.5];
[_window setBackgroundColor:semiTransparentBlue];
```

If I move it to another class, putting it into

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame, or
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect,
```

with
    #import "AppDelegate.h" 
in the class.h,
it compiles correctly but fails to change the window, even though breakpoints show that it is being accessed.

Why does it have to be in AppDelegate? Do all window changes have to be in AppDelegate? Is there a reference that explains?

I have not been able to find any guidance with extensive Googling. Apple docs show lines of code that show what to do, but not where to place them.

Comment: This is tagged iOS but you reference Cocoa classes.

Comment: How are you getting your reference _window?

Comment: There is no requirement that a given line of code execute in a given module in order to achieve it's function.  What's necessary is that it execute at the appropriate time, with the appropriate data.  Somehow you're not executing the code at the correct time or you do not have the correct data.  Best guess is that `_window` is nil when the code is executed.

Comment: maddy: Somehow this has been tagged ios -- first -- although I selected Xcode, objective-c, and ios. I believe it pertains to all. I'm using an iMac.

Comment: picciano: as I mentioned above, with #import "AppDelegate.h" in the class.h

Comment: nil sounds right, but how do I make it execute at the proper time, other than place it in AppDelegate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing the code that initiates your "other class" which is probably a subclass of UIView, its a hunch but...

_window is probably not set properly. You can get a reference to the main window by calling

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate].window

try setting colour and opaque on that.

Comment: Sorry, I'm in OSX, not ios.

Comment: Sorry, I'm in OSX, not ios. Bad news: Something new is going on. I just tried moving the code to the other class again, but now it generates the  error "Initializer element is not a compile-time constant", which never happened before. I have no idea how to deal with this.